# Get Class of Each Parent <td> and map it to an <li> item using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem which I have half solved myself and need some experts to help me finish it off.

I have a `<table>` and I want to populate a `.dropdown` with the names in my first column and their parent class name (numerical) applied to the `input` checkbox field within the `<li>`that I add to the dropdown.

**DEMO - http://jsfiddle.net/zqMnk/2/**

1. I have the names working
2. I don't know how to also add the class name (For question purposes I named it in demo to `addDynamicClassHere`)

**Notes**

1. Sometimes the class name is mixed with other classes so I do a `replace` to strip out the unwanted. See `var addDynamicClassHere =` in demo JS. This is my attempt at getting the class name.
2. I have added a class `addDynamicClassHere` to the `input` which is where I want to apply the corresponding class.

If I look at the HTML of **just the input** fields in the dropdown I would expect the result to be

```
<input class="520e248" type="checkbox" checked="">
<input class="520e24ee8" type="checkbox" checked="">
<input class="e248" type="checkbox" checked="">
<input class="434343" type="checkbox" checked="">
<input class="90i0i" type="checkbox" checked="">
```

Please note this is just me showing you the inputs desired results for question purposes, there is other html around them as u see in demo.

Thanks in advance...Difficult question to phrase correctly so please let me know if any questions and I can edit...

Comment: When do you want the dynamic class to be added , once the user clicks a particular name, is it ?

Comment: On Page load I wanted the dropdown names and classes to be added.

Comment: class names aren't supposed to be numeric only.

Comment: thanks for the comment. We are not using the class names in css to style them, it was just a way of identifying the div and a class was easiest to add for dev on Backend. It seems to work OK, is it just better practice not to use numbers only or will I see any issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the classes like this

```
var addDynamicClassHere = $('.pickme').closest('tr').map(function () {
    return this.className.replace(/(first|hidden)/g,"");
});
```

I'm guessing you want to show/hide depending on if it is checked or not, then you could do it like this

```
   $('.resourceFilter').on('change', 'input', function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            console.log("show");
            $('tr.' + this.className).show();
        } else {
            $('tr.' + this.className).hide();
        }
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zqMnk/5/)